# Getting error as "nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream" when executing nginx -s reload

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

We are deploying reactjs app into nginx and after the deployment we are getting that error.
Also we want to route the url to https://example.org/reactjs. Below are the changes which we are doing in `tools_context.conf` file as find below in image. Please find attached the docker file details as well.

[image]

[image: dockerfile]

```
FROM node:10-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV "production"
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000
RUN addgroup mygroup && adduser -D -G mygroup myuser && mkdir -p /usr/src/app && chown -R myuser /usr/src/app

# Prepare app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
#COPY yarn.lock /usr/src/app/
#RUN chown myuser /usr/src/app/yarn.lock

USER myuser
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

# Start the app
CMD ["npm", "run", "startenter code here"]
```

Comment: Please do not post text as images and use text instead (wrapping it in a `code block`). It is crucial to be able to copy-paste your code/configs/etc. to reproduce the issue, and images do not allow this.

Comment: @DanilaKiver- Done